# Mocking OpenAI Chat Client

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, openai-api

How can the OpenAIClient be mocked using MOQ to return a Completions response? I have a json response and would like to deserialize that to `Response<Completions>`.

```
      private OpenAIClient client = // initialize;
    
      private async Task<Response<Completions>> Complete(string model, string prompt) =>
          await client.GetCompletionsAsync(model, prompt);
```

The below attempt to return a response failed as the Completions class does not contain a constructor that can be used to deserialize the json response -

```
private readonly Mock<OpenAIClient> client= new();
          client
              .Setup(x => x.GetCompletionsAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
              .ReturnsAsync(Response.FromValue(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Completions>(completionsJson), Mock.Of<Response>()));
```

The Completions class constructor is marked as `internal` and so are all the objects within the Completions class.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0#specific-type

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. When I checked further the completions class is marked as internal. So is that only way to create a mock object is using reflections?

Comment: See following https://code-maze.com/unit-testing-controllers-aspnetcore-moq/.  I'm not an expert in MOQ.  You have a HTTP Request/Response.  The controller is a utility to help send/receive HTTP in Net.  The class data is the body of the HTTP Request/Response.  When you send you serialize the data and when you receive you deserialize the data.  I serialize/deserialize is not usually referred to as REFLECTION although the library may use reflection.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. I assume I need to construct the `Response<Completions>` object for the mock to return this object. However it looks like there isn't a way to construct this object because the constructor is marked as internal for this class.

Comment: Create an instance of the public parent class.  From the instance run the constructor.

Comment: Sorry, which is the parent class that you mentioned? Since Completions does not have a public constructor, I was planning on giving Reflections a shot to do this.

Comment: The parent class of OpenAIClient